# Android: ListActivity and ArrayAdapter - sorting before displaying List

Tags: android, multithreading

Ive got a ListActivity that has a ArrayAdapter and a Filter. I want to fill the ArrayAdapter's items up, filter the results then display them. For whatever reason there is some fancy threading going on that forces the result to be displayed without applying the filter first, then it filters. So there is a tenth of a second where you can see non-filtered results.

Run within the UI thread on the ListActivity

```
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        if (promotionItems != null && promotionItems.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < promotionItems.size(); i++)
                m_adapter.add(promotionItems.get(i));
        }

        m_adapter.getFilter().filter(filterString);
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess you could alternatively filter them outside of the adapter and then pass them on once they're ready. I'm not sure why the changes are showing before you make the call to notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Don't forget you can't modify the UI from another thread. Perhaps calling notifydatasetchanged in that thread is the issue. Trying using a handler and the the updating there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look on [ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange%28boolean%29)? Sounds like it's something you want to disable before adding any of your items to ArrayAdapter in this particular case.